# gvfs-trash fails to trash

Tags: trash, gvfs

I'm trying to use `gvfs-trash`, and I get an error.

```
$ trash thefile
Error trashing file: Unable to find or create trash directory
```

How can I fix this?

```
$ ls -ld ~/.local/share/Trash/
drwx------ 4 username username 4096 Jul 24 22:23 /home/username/.local/share/Trash/

ls -ld ~/.local/share/
drwx------ 3 username username 4096 Jul 24 22:23 /home/username/.local/share/
```

Comment: Where is thefile located?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -ld ~/.local/share/Trash/` and `ls -ld ~/.local/share/`.

Comment: @ByteCommander Edited.

Comment: As muru already asked, where is the file located you want to trash? Is it on your root partition or another partition on your internal disk or on any external medium like USB sticks?

Comment: @muru it is on the root partition. It's in a subsub directory of /var/ where I am a group member, not the directory owner. I am able to `gvfs-trash` files in `~`.

Answer (score 6):

When you trash a file that's not on the same partition on your home directory, it's [moved to the **.Trash-1000** directory](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gvfs-trash.1.html#contenttoc3) on the root of whatever partition you are.
Make sure that directory **.Trash-1000** is **writable** for the user under which you want to trash the file.

I got the same failure too, my root partition was different than my home directory - which is a encrypted partition. The directory /.Trash-1000 was not writable by the current user I was logged in.
Solved by running

`sudo chown MYUSERNAME /.Trash-1000`